# Cypress: Invoking text and assigning to a variable, but not able to use?

Tags: cypress

This code is working fine.

```
var txt
        cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
        cy.get('label[for="exampleInputEmail1"]').invoke('text').then((text)=>{
            txt = text
            cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(txt)
        })
```

This is not working, though I am getting an error of "You passed in: undefined". I am not sure how this works!

```js
var txt
        cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
        cy.get('label[for="exampleInputEmail1"]').invoke('text').then((text)=>{
            txt = text
        })
        cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(txt)
```

Can someone explain how this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress preference is to use alias instead of variables. You can read more about it here [Variables and aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases).

```js
cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
cy.get('label[for="exampleInputEmail1"]').invoke('text')
  .as('labelText')

// later in the test
cy.get('@labelText').then(txt => {
  cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(txt)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working but please confirm whenever I need to use the 'labelText', I should write .get('@labelText').then(( )) throughout the Project?

Comment: You can use any name for the alias for example `.as('someOtherNameHere')` as long as the matching command has that name with `@` in front e.g `cy.get('@someOtherNameHere')`. Lots more details in the docs I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the global variable `text`, you can do directly like this:

```js
cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
cy.get('label[for="exampleInputEmail1"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(text)
  })
```

Because of the asynchronous nature of javascript, the txt value is used before it is getting updated with the inner text value. To prevent that you have to use a `then` like this:

```js
var txt
cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
cy.get('label[for="exampleInputEmail1"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    txt = text
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(txt)
  })
```

Another way would be to use the `Cypress.env()` variable, if you want to use the text value anywhere within the project or test.

```js
cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
cy.get('label[for="exampleInputEmail1"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    Cypress.env('label', text) //Set the text
  })
cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(Cypress.env('label')) //Get text and type
```

Comment: Yes that works but I am unable to use outside of then block, though I tried to assign to a variable and use it.

Comment: Both the ways are allowing me to use only inside then block, I couldn't get the label text outside of the then block.

Comment: Use the `Cypress.env` method, that should work for you. Assuming that you have a valid inner text at your selector.

Comment: cy.get('#exampleInputPassword1').type(Cypress.env('label')); this line I could able to use inside then block only and when I write outside I am getting an error as "cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined"